# Windows 8.1, volume in center of screen

Tags: windows, audio

I finally updated to 8.1 and now whenever I adjust my computer's volume, a volume slider appears in the center of the screen.

This is in addition to the normal volume slider that appears in the upper left. The slider in the center lasts about twice as long as the one in the upper left (about ten seconds).

I haven't been able to find anyone else online who has this problem.

While the slider is on the screen, I'm able to drag it around on the screen, but after it disappears it reappears back in the center next time I adjust the volume. Any thoughts?

This is what my desktop looks like after adjusting the volume:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the Dell volume control icon.

In the system tray at the bottom right, locate the Dell Quickset Icon, right (or left, whichever works) click once on the QuickSet Icon, you should get a menu. Go to "Hotkey Popups" -> Disable On Screen Volume Meter.

If you don't have the Quickset, search in your computer if it's called Dell system manager or any similar names.